# Differentiate $ \sqrt x$ from first principles

Tags: derivatives

Find the derivative of $f(x)= \sqrt x$

This is what I have done

$y+δy=\sqrt{x+δx}$

$δy=\sqrt{x+δx}-\sqrt x$

$δy^2=x+δx-x$

So  $δy^2=δx$, 
which then becomes $\frac{δy^2}{δx}$

How do you get rid of the square?

Comment: You passage to $\delta y^2$ is wrong. From $a=\sqrt b-\sqrt c$ it **does not** follow that $a^2=b-c$. Indeed one rather has $(\sqrt b-\sqrt c)^=b-2\sqrt{bc}+c$. To transform $\sqrt b-\sqrt c$ into $b-c$ don't take the square, but multiply by $\sqrt b+\sqrt c$ instead.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at it as follows:

$$\sqrt {x+\delta x}-\sqrt x =\left(\sqrt {x+\delta x}-\sqrt x\right) \cdot \frac {\sqrt {x+\delta x}+\sqrt x }{\sqrt {x+\delta x}+\sqrt x}=\frac {\delta x}{\sqrt {x+\delta x}+\sqrt x }$$

Now the denominator is "large" compared with $\delta x$ and you don't need to get rid of the square root.

It looks as though you have done the equivalent of $(a-b)^2=a^2-b^2$, which is not true, and what you need instead is $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$, as I have used above.

Answer (score 0):

$ \dfrac{f(x+\delta x)-f(x)}{(x+\delta x)-x}=\dfrac{\sqrt{x+\delta x}-\sqrt{x}}{\delta x}=\dfrac{(\sqrt{x+\delta  x}-\sqrt{x})(\sqrt{x+\delta x}+\sqrt{x})}{\delta x (\sqrt{x+\delta x}+\sqrt{x})}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x+\delta x}+\sqrt{x}} $